# Changing specific html table row by jquery.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have an HTML table generated by PHP querying from MySQL table.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Sl</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Article Name</th>
      <th>Publish Status</th>
   </tr>
   <?php
      $i = 1;
      foreach ($obj->showAllFromTable('pattern') as $pattern) {
      extract($pattern);
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $pattern_name; ?></td>
      <td id="publish_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="status_pattern">
         <?php echo $publish; ?>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }           
      ?>
</table>
```

I want to change the status of any article by clicking on the 'publish' cell of the corresponding article row. I am trying to use ajax method of jquery for this purpose as shown in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('.status_pattern').click(function(){
    var thisid = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: "status_change_pattern.php",
        data: {
            id: thisid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

In the "success" block, instead of "alert", I want to create a functionality to change the text of the specific cell which I clicked. The "status_change_pattern.php" has just a text "Hey Hey".
Can anyone help? Please.
Thanks.

Comment: instead of text try `html()`

Comment: what is the code of your `status_change_pattern.php`?

Comment: @SatishSharma: It is just a text "Hey Hey". I just want to change the text of the "publish" cell to "Hey Hey". My problem is that I cannot seem to target the specific cell to change its text. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `closure` to preserve the id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.status_pattern').click(function(){
        var thisid = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: "status_change_pattern.php",
            data: {
                id: thisid
            },
            success: function (id) {
                return function (response) {
                    $("#" + id).html(response);
                }
            }(thisid)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. But its not working. There is a problem in your code, the ; after the last (thisid). With this in code, even the other jquery codes stop working. Removing the ; makes the other codes to work. But with or without the ; the main purpose is not fulfilled.

Comment: OK I removed the `;`, but can you please alert `id`. Just above the $(id) statement

Comment: Yes!! the alert id is showing the ids!!. But $(id).html(response) is not working.

Comment: If you have any alternative solutions for this, kindly suggest.

Comment: I have updated my answer, we need to give a "#" + id to select the ID in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to write,

```
success: function (response) {
            $(thisid).html(response);
        }
```

Here in response, you need to get new status.

Comment: No, I does not work. The problem is that I cant seem to be able to target the specific cell to change its text.

Comment: are you getting 'Hey Hey' in alert(response)?

Comment: Yes I am getting 'Hey Hey' in alert(response)

Comment: I think there are duplicate IDs of ID. What is $id? is it same for all or different?

Comment: No there is no duplicate ID.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by SajithNair works. Thanks to SajithNair. But it can also be done without using closure. As shown below:

```
    $('.status_pattern').click(function() {
        var thisid = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url : "status_change_pattern.php",
            data : {
                id : thisid
            },
            success : function(response) {
                $('#' + thisid).html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks